# Call to php not working in IE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onchange

I'm launching the below javascript with an onChange event in the html:

I've verified that the onChange event is getting to the javascript by doing a simple alert("working"); and IE did fire up the alert, however the actual code that I want does not seem to work. (its functional in FF, Chrome, Safari, iPad, and Android).

What the function does is: take the value passed to it through the onchange, and send it to a php file as a variable. The php file takes the variable it gets and inserts it into a DB. I don't think the php portion is the problem because it works in every other browser. Does anyone have any insight?

Code:

```
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://testest.com/itgoeshere.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I realize that have to explicitly add value attributes to each  tag, as you must do so for I.E. But I believe I have done this...

Here's an example for what the select statement looks like...

```
<select name="date" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="1">Past hour</option>
<option value="2">Past week</option>
<option value="3">Past month</option>
<option value="4">Past year</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is `txtHint`? What does _not working_ mean?

Comment: txtHint is an ID i believe. By not working I mean that the value is not being inserted into the MYSQL db.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how to get a log on this because I don't know where the errors go. It is an "onChange" that is suppose to fire the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. you can try the [jQuery Ajax Function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for testing (jQuery should support IE6).

Perhaps the [described workaround](https://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/macvittie/archive/2008/06/26/3397.aspx) (Fixing Internet Explorer & AJAX) can fix the problem.

jQuery Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "getitinhere.php",
  async: true,          
  data: { "str": str },
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Success: '+data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){  
    alert('Something went wrong' +textStatus);          
  }
});
```

Hope this snippet can help you ;)

Comment: I read the page, as well as other resources. So something like this in the script? (Pretty new with jQuery)


function showUser(str)
{
$.ajax({url: "getitinhere.php", type: "get", data: {"str": str}})
}

Comment: yeah that looks good, you can also add a success and/or error callback function like this